# linearGradient not working for SVG sprites

Tags: html, svg, sprite, linear-gradients, sprite-sheet

I am trying to combine all svg icons into one sprite file [like this](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/) for organization, caching and other purposes. But for some reason, `linearGradient` is not being applied

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <svg version="1.1" id="icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
   y="0px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
    <!-- other icons -->
    <!-- ... -->
    <g id="toggle">
      <path d="M4,7.992c-2.206,0-4-1.794-4-4c0-2.206,1.794-4,4-4h10c2.206,0,4,1.794,4,4c0,2.206-1.794,4-4,4H4z"/>
      <circle fill="url('#toggle-linear-gradient')" cx="14" cy="3.992" r="3"/>
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="toggle-linear-gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="14" y1="0.9922" x2="14" y2="6.9922">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFFFFF"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#8C8C8B"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Now, in file preview I can see circle with applied gradient correctly

[image: in svg file preview]

When I try to import it into my HTML like this

```
<svg>
  <use href="#toggle" xlink:href="#toggle"></use>
</svg>
```

the circle is not being colored with defined gradient

[image: in the page]

When I moved `<linearGradient>` out of svg file, it worked, but why?

```
<svg>
  <linearGradient id="toggle-linear-gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="14" y1="0.9922" x2="14" y2="6.9922">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#8C8C8B"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <use href="#toggle" xlink:href="#toggle"></use>
</svg>
```

[image: with linearGradient outside svg file]

Even tho it worked, the problem is, that this kills the purpose of keeping all the icons in one file if some styling can only be defined from the outside. Displaying same icon will force me defining same gradient multiple times. Would love to have everything in the same file. Any ideas or insights?

P.S. importing as `<img>` displays the circle gradient correctly.

Comment: use Firefox. Chrome does not currently support this. I think it might be [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212)

Comment: Actually maybe [it's this one](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=229081)

Comment: From your code it looks like the "sprite SVG" is part of the current HTML document -- is that correct? It is not your intention to move the sprite SVG to an external file, so you would refer to it using `<use href="spritesheet.svg#toggle" />`. I don't know if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure, you have hidden your main svg asset file by `display:none`.

If you change this to `visibility:hidden` it should work:

```js
function unhide(){
  document.querySelector('.dsp-non').classList.remove('dsp-non');
}
```

```css
.svgAssetHidden{
  visibility:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.svgIcon{
  display:inline-block;
  width:10em;
}

.dsp-non{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="unhide()">remove display:none</button>

<h3>visibility:hidden</h3>
<svg class="svgIcon" viewBox="0 0 50 20">
  <use href="#toggle" href="#toggle"></use>
</svg>

<h3>display:none</h3>
<svg class="svgIcon" viewBox="0 0 50 20">
  <use href="#toggle2" href="#toggle"></use>
</svg>

<svg class="svgAssetHidden" id="icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
   y="0px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
    <!-- other icons -->
    <!-- ... -->
    <g id="toggle">
      <path d="M4,7.992c-2.206,0-4-1.794-4-4c0-2.206,1.794-4,4-4h10c2.206,0,4,1.794,4,4c0,2.206-1.794,4-4,4H4z"/>
      <circle fill="url('#toggle-linear-gradient')" cx="14" cy="3.992" r="3"/>
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="toggle-linear-gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="14" y1="0.9922" x2="14" y2="6.9922">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFFFFF"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#8C8C8B"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    </g>
  </svg>


<svg class="svgAssetDspNon dsp-non" id="icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
   y="0px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
    <!-- other icons -->
    <!-- ... -->
    <g id="toggle2">
      <path d="M4,7.992c-2.206,0-4-1.794-4-4c0-2.206,1.794-4,4-4h10c2.206,0,4,1.794,4,4c0,2.206-1.794,4-4,4H4z"/>
      <circle fill="url('#toggle-linear-gradient2')" cx="14" cy="3.992" r="3"/>
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="toggle-linear-gradient2" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="14" y1="0.9922" x2="14" y2="6.9922">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFFFFF"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#8C0000"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Hiding a svg by `display:none` will also break some other features like filters.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you