# SVG <linearGradient/> element not working in React Sprite component

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js, css-sprites

I want to use react sprite component (`<Icon id={"test"}/>`) to render the SVG files in which there are `linearGradient` properties to define the filled color.

However, the icon cannot be rendered property if the linearGradient filled color is adopted.

### the `Icon` component code (icon.tsx):

```
import React from "react";

import sprite from "~/public/icons/sprite.svg";

interface IconProps {
  name: string;
  className?: string;
}

const Icon: React.FC<IconProps> = ({ name, className }) => {
  return (
    <svg className={className}>
      <use xlinkHref={`${sprite}#${name}`} />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default Icon;
```

### The sprite.svg code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="visibility:hidden">
  <symbol
  id="test"
      width="24"
      height="24"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      
          <path
            d="M14.1 13.9L12.9 10.7L9.6 9.49999C8.8 9.09999 8.2 8.29999 8.2 7.39999C8.2 7.29999 8.2 7.19999 8.2 7.09999C4.4 7.69999 1.5 11 1.5 14.9C1.5 19.3 5.1 22.9 9.5 22.9C13.9 22.9 17.5 19.3 17.5 14.9C17.1 15.2 16.7 15.3 16.2 15.3C15.2 15.4 14.4 14.8 14.1 13.9Z"
            fill="url(#paint1_linear_925_2107)"
            
          />
          <path
            d="M16.7 1.39999L18.1 5.09999C18.2 5.29999 18.3 5.39999 18.4 5.39999L22.1 6.79999C22.6 6.99999 22.6 7.69999 22.1 7.89999L18.4 9.29999C18.2 9.39999 18.1 9.49999 18.1 9.59999L16.7 13.3C16.5 13.8 15.8 13.8 15.6 13.3L14.2 9.59999C14.1 9.39999 14 9.29999 13.9 9.29999L10.2 7.89999C9.69995 7.69999 9.69995 6.99999 10.2 6.79999L13.9 5.39999C14.1 5.29999 14.2 5.19999 14.2 5.09999L15.6 1.39999C15.8 0.899994 16.5 0.899994 16.7 1.39999Z"
            fill="url(#paint1_linear_925_2107)"
          />
        
      <defs>
        <linearGradient
          id="paint0_linear_925_2107"
          x1="9.504"
          y1="22.9528"
          x2="9.504"
          y2="7.06029"
          gradient-units="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop stop-color="#F5A700" />
          <stop offset="0.6882" stop-color="#FBB600" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFBF00" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="paint1_linear_925_2107"
          x1="16.1811"
          y1="13.685"
          x2="16.1811"
          y2="1.04719"
          gradient-units="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop stop-color="#F5D75D" />
          <stop offset="0.2656" stop-color="#F7DC6C" />
          <stop offset="0.7778" stop-color="#FCEA95" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFF0A8" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    </symbol>
  
  <!-- More symbols here... -->
</svg>
```

I tried both removing the `<defs>` out of symbol [(recommended here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76510076/render-svg-symbol-sprite-with-lineargradient) and changing the SVG `display` property to `visibility: hidden` [(recommended here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70663671/lineargradient-not-working-for-svg-sprites). Neither of them works in my case.

Could anybody coming across a similar situation give me a hint?

NOTE:

- 1. it works only if I change the `fill` to a particular color. for example, `fill="white"`
- 2. The project is powered by Next.js

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1385248